# Entity Framework 4.1 Dynamically retrieve mapped column name

Tags: entity, metadata, entity-framework-4.1

I am trying to construct an SQL statement dynamically.

My context is created dynamically, using reflection finding classes deriving from EntityTypeConfiguration and adding them to DbModelBuilder.Configuration.

My EntityTypeConfiguration classes specify HasColumnName to map the Entity property name to db table column name, which I need to construct my SQL statement.

```
namespace MyDomain {
    public class TestEntityConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<TestEntity>{
        Property("Name").HasColumnName("dbName");
    } 
 }
```

From What I have researched, it seems I can get access to this information through MetadataWorkspace, which I can get to through ObjectContext.

I have managed to retrieve the the entity I am interested in with MetadataWorkspace.GetItem("MyDomain.TestEntity",DataSpace.OSpace), which gives me access to Properties, but none of the properties, of Properties, give me the name of the mapped db column, as specified with HasColumnName.

Also I am not clear what DataSpace.OSpace is and why my model is constructed in this space.

If Anyone can shed some light on this I would be grateful

### UPDATE

Further to @Ladislav's comments. I discovered I can get the information as follows
For the class properties

```
ctx.MetadataWorkspace.GetItem<ClrEntityType>("MyDomain.TestEntity", DataSpace.OSpace)).Members
```

For the table properties

```
ctx.MetadataWorkspace.GetItem<EntityType>("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.TestEntity",SSpace).Members
```

So given that I only know the type MyDomain.TestEntity and Memeber "Name". How would I go about to get "dbName". Can I always assume that my mapped class will be created in CodeFirstDatabaseSchema, om order to dynamically construct the identity to retrieve it from SSpace and how would I get to the correct Member in SSpace. Can I do something like

```
var memIndex = ctx.MetadataWorkspace.GetItem<ClrEntityType>("MyDomain.TestEntity", DataSpace.OSpace)).Members["Name"].Index;

var dbName = ctx.MetadataWorkspace.GetItem<EntityType>("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.TestEntity",SSpace).Members[memIndex];
```

Comment: ClrEntityType is internal to System.Data.Entity. How are you doing this call? Reflection?

Answer (score 0):

`MetadataWorkspace` contanis several containers specified by `DataSpace`. Interesting for you are:

- CSpace - description of conceptual model (this should contain properties)
- CSSpace - mapping of conceptual model to storage model (this should contain how classes / properties are mapped to tables / columns)

Comment: Thank you. I did not find the slution precisely where you indicated, but it got me looking in the other DataSpaces and I am now a little closer to solving this. Could you please look at my updated and clarify further if possible